# How do I stop emacs from asking me if I want to load a large file?

Tags: emacs

When I open a large file in emacs, I get a message saying 'foo.bar file is large; really open?'

How do I stop emacs from asking me this question all the time? In other words, if I open the file, I want to open the file, no matter how big it is.

Comment: Answer is available here:
http://superuser.com/questions/508498/how-can-i-disable-emacs-dialogue-file-xxx-is-really-big-really-wants-to-open-i

(setq large-file-warning-threshold nil)

Comment: Gilles' answer below is more complete and will teach you how to solve your next problems.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

#### Via the manual

In the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html) (which you can browse inside Emacs in Info: `C-h i m Emacs RET`): go to the chapter on [files](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Files.html#Files), then to the section on [visiting](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Visiting.html#Visiting) (i.e. opening) files. Look for the word “large”:

> If you try to visit a file larger than `large-file-warning-threshold` (the default is 10000000, which is about 10 megabytes), Emacs asks you for confirmation first. You can answer y to proceed with visiting the file.

This is not the whole story, you can find more information by looking at the documentation of `large-file-warning-threshold` (`C-h v large-file-warning-threshold RET`).

> large-file-warning-threshold is a variable defined in `files.el`.
> Its value is 10000000
>
> Maximum size of file above which a confirmation is requested.
> When nil, never request confirmation.

To set the value, you can either use the Customize interface (there's a link in the help screen for the variable), or put the following statement in your `.emacs`:

```
(setq large-file-warning-threshold nil)
```

Type `C-M-x` while the point is on that line to execute it now.

#### In the Customize interface

Under “Files”, under “Find Files”, there is a setting “Large File Warning Threshold”. You can set it to a large value, though on a 32-bit machine you may run into Emacs's relatively small hard limit on integer sizes.

#### By reading the source

Look at the function to open files: `C-h k C-x C-f` (or `C-h f find-file RET`). Click on `files.el` to browse the source file (you must have the Lisp sources installed). Don't read the code — it's pretty big — but search for parts of the message in that file. You'll find

```
(defun abort-if-file-too-large (size op-type filename)
  "If file SIZE larger than `large-file-warning-threshold', allow user to abort.
OP-TYPE specifies the file operation being performed (for message to user)."
  (when (and large-file-warning-threshold size
       (> size large-file-warning-threshold)
       (not (y-or-n-p
         (format "File %s is large (%dMB), really %s? "
             (file-name-nondirectory filename)
             (/ size 1048576) op-type))))
      (error "Aborted")))
```

The message is only displayed when some conditions are met. The first condition is `large-file-warning-threshold` (interpreted as a boolean), i.e. `large-file-warning-threshold` must be non-nil. So you can disable the message by setting that variable to `nil`. (You can confirm that it's a global variable by looking at its definition in the same file — it's a customizable item, and the documentation explains how it's used if you aren't familiar enough with Lisp and only figured out that the variable mattered in some way.)

Comment: To open the emacs manual "C-h r" is easier than "C-h i m Emacs RET"

Comment: Still correct, except for the small bit (nitpicky, I know ;-)) where the "File %s is large" isn't in abort-if-file-too-large anymore, it's been moved to a helper function files--ask-user-about-large-file at some point between 2014 and Emacs 29.